# Prove that three lines intersect at the same point using equal perpendicular distances?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Background:** I am trying to prove that reflections are an isometry, i.e., $d(P,Q)=d(f(P),f(Q))$ when $f$ is a reflection across the line $\ell$.

**Main question:** Is there a proof to state that the lines $\overline{PQ}$ and $\overline{f(P)f(Q)}$ both intersect $\ell$ at the same point $C$? I have included an illustration below with these labels.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOFca.png)

**Additional info:** My main goal is to prove that the distances of $[P,Q]$ and $[f(P),f(Q)]$. If I can prove the above, I will then use Thales' Theorem and the fact that $[C,P,Q]$ is an isosceles triangle to show that these distances are indeed equal.

Comment: When you reflect over $l$, no points on the line are moved.  So, any point of intersection will not be moved anywhere.  What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Let $PQ$ intersects $l$ at $C$, $D$ is middle of $PP'$, $E$ is middle of $QQ'$. $D$ and $E$ lie at $l$ and $\angle PDC=\angle QEC=90$°. Then triangles $PCD$ and $QCE$ are similar. Then congruent triangles $P'CD$ and $Q'CE$ are also similar. Then $\angle ECQ'=\angle DCP'$, then $CQ'$ pass through $P'$.